# How to count number of rows in a list with "string" in it?

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist, count

I have a list like this:

```
["hi","hello","one"]
["hi","hello1","two"]
["hi1","hello3","three"]
```

Is there a more efficient way to count number of rows with the string "hi" in it so that the result be **2** besides looping? A command like `listCount()`?

Comment: No matter what method you use, it internally has loops.

Comment: stream java 8 can do it

Comment: could you guys give me a sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Java 8 stream:

```
long count = strings.stream()
                    .flatMap(List::stream)
                    .filter(Predicate.isEqual("hi"))
                    .count();
```

... assuming you have a `strings` variable like this:

```
List<List<String>> strings = asList(asList("hi", "hello", "one"),
                                    asList("hi", "hello1", "two"),
                                    asList("hi1", "hello3", "three"));
```

If you instead have nested arrays, you can still use streams, but you'll have to adjust the code above.

If your list is large, you can probably make it faster by starting the stream with `strings.parallelStream()` instead of `strings.stream()`, which will make sure your available cores are used for parallel processing.

Comment: How many loop the Stream will use ? flatMap will probably iterate once, filter too... even hidden, this is still two loops

Comment: @AxelH: Now you're only guessing. Streams will build a processing pipeline and traverse the data once. For more complex streams than this one, it will use optimisations like short-circuit and laziness. It will also take advantage on you multicore cpu if you use parallel streams...

Comment: Hey, just asking... I keep seeing Stream's solution everywhere without any explanation about why this is better in that case and not simply with iteration. Know the comment section have the answer !

Comment: @AxelH: There is a summary of Java 8 streams here: [Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html). I can also recommend reading the book [Java 8 in action](https://www.manning.com/books/java-8-in-action) if you want to learn more.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it, well I was speaking about SO and solution without any explanation. But I will take a look at it (even if I can use it for the job...)